# aws cloudfront. Is it possible to increase quota on header size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

Aws has quota 1,783 characters for the custom headers value.
Is it possible to increase the quota on header value?

Comment: How did it go? Did my answer, answered your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html#limits-custom-headers) there is no option for `Custom headers: maximum length of a header value` to request an increase.